# help me for writing an sql query

Tags: postgresql

[image: image showing previous row values and current row values]

I want to write a query to select all the rows where the row value changes from previous row. Please see the image attached above.

```
CREATE TABLE traffview.status_data (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    site_id integer,
    rtc timestamp without time zone,
    sigplan smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

INSERT INTO traffview.status_data(
    id,
    site_id,
    rtc,
    sigplan
    )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: Define "previous".

Comment: ie, if signal plan value in a field changes from that of above row for aparicular controller

Comment: Welcome to the site, please post `create table` statements and `insert` statements (or create an http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6 or similar).

Comment: CREATE TABLE traffview.status_data
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  site_id integer,
  rtc timestamp without time zone,
  sigplan smallint,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: INSERT INTO traffview.status_data(
            id, site_id, rtc, sigplan)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);

Comment: Thanks for the create table statement, now all that's missing is insert statements for the data .... Don't post it as comments, update your question.

Comment: And please provide data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WITH cte(id, controller_id, RTC, signal_plan, rw) AS 
(
     SELECT
         id,
         controller_id,
         RTC,
         signal_plan,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY signal_plan ORDER BY id) rw
     FROM your_table)

     SELECT
         id,
         controller_id,
         RTC,
         signal_plan
     FROM cte
     WHERE rw = 1;
```

Comment: shows an error like this     ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 8:          ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY  sigplan ORDER BY i...

Comment: @sangeetha whats the full message?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 8:          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  sigplan ORDER BY id...
                           ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
SQL state: 42601
Character: 150

Comment: @sangeetha try putting a space after OVER

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: @sangeetha Have a read about ROW_NUMBER() function, see if you can work it out :)

Comment: Thanks! the query worked. But the table contains lot of data. so its taking too long to execute. I have provided LIMIT. Could you give any suggestion?

Comment: I wonder how this query "worked". And my question is not to the answerer, who did what it could best with the tiny information that was provided by the OP. @sangeetha, edit your question and provide, first the data in text format (not image) and what exactly is wanted.